# How to select/pipe a filename out of "git status" in bash

Tags: git, bash

So I'm on the command line and type "git status".  Often the next thing I want to do is copy one filename to open in my editor.

Anyone know a trick to programatically select the nth file listed by "git status" and copy it into memory? (shell is bash)

Comment: Do you want just the modified files or added and deleted files as well? It's easy enough to write a short program or alias to extract information from git status (although there are probably git plumbing commands as well that do what you want directly)

Comment: Pipe the output of `git ls-files --modified` into whatever program you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pipeline that you can use to select the nth "modified" item from git status.

```
$ git status | grep '^.modified' | cut -d: -f2- | sed -e 's/^...//' | awk 'NR == 1'
```

Here's how it works: `git status` produces the full output

```
grep '^.modified'
```

selects just the lines that begin with modified (with one character before for the tab)

```
cut -d: -f2-
```

Give us everything after the first colon

```
sed -e 's/...//'
```

delete the first three characters (spaces)

```
awk 'NR == 1'
```

select the first line, you can replace this with whatever you want.

You can copy any shell value into a variable by using `$(...)`

```
files=$(ls) # copies the contents of ls into the shell variable files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git status | grep 'new file:' | cut -f2 -d:
   file1
   file2
   file3
```

Or, you can further perfecting the output without the leading white space:

```
git status | grep 'new file:' | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/^ *//'
file1
file2
file3
```